# File Binding

Tags: bindingsource

How can i learn how to bind 2 files into one? Are there any tutorials out there i cant seem to find. Theres only for VB.NEt.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind" 2 files? Append them? Interlace different lines? Put them side by side? Something else?

Comment: If you can find a good tutorial for VB.Net, then it is often quite easy to convert to C# since the structure is usually very similar so maybe you could just convert the code, there's an online converter at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Meaning  eg. binding 2 exe files into 1 .exe file. Once this exe file runs both files run together